# How to convert pandas dataframe to defaultdict (class, list) where one of the column values is used as keys?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension, defaultdict

In the given pandas dataframe:

```
df = 

     contig       pos  PI_index  hapX_My_Sum  hapY_My_Sum  hapX_Sp_Sum       
 0  2  16229767           726          0.0         12.0          3.5   
 1  2  16229783           726          0.0         12.0          3.5   
 3  2  16229880           726          0.0         12.0          2.0   
 4  2  16230491           255         12.0          0.0          0.0   
 5  2  16230503           255         12.0          0.0          0.0   
 6  2  16232072           255         11.0          1.0          0.0   
 7  2  16232072           255         11.0          1.0          0.0   
 8  2  16232282          3353         11.0          1.0          0.0   
 9  2  16232444          3353         11.0          1.0          0.0   
 10 2  16232444          3353         11.0          1.0          0.0
```

I want to convert this dataframe to `dictionary of dictionary` i.e `default(dict)`

So, I did:

```
from collections import defaultdict
df_dict = df.to_dict('index')

print(df_dict)  # gives me
{0: {'hapY_My_Sum': 12.0, 'hapX_Sp_Sum': 3.5 .....}
```

All, is good but instead of using the `main pandas index` I want to use the `PI_index` as the indexes to generate `defaultdict(<class 'dict'>` where `PI_index` values are the `keys` to do downstream analyses.

**The print output of the `defaultdict` should be like:**

`defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'726': {'contig': '2', 'hapX_My_Sum': ['0.0', '0.0', '0.0'], 'hapY_My_Sum': ['12.0', '12.0', '12.0'], ....}, '255':{'contig': '2', 'hapX_My_Sum': [....]....}})`

**Post edit:**

- I forgot to add but is there a way to **unselected** certain columns if undesired, but I don't want to drop them out from pandas data frame.
- Also, what if I only want one value in **contig** since they will all be the same.

So, downstream I can do something like:

```
for k in df_dict:
    contig = df_dict[k]['chr']

    hapX_My_product = reduce(mul, (float(x) for x in (df_dict[k]['hapX_My_Sum'])))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
In [11]: cols = ['contig','PI_index','hapX_My_Sum']

In [12]: df[cols].groupby('PI_index') \
                 .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('PI_index').to_dict('list')) \
                 .to_dict()
Out[12]:
{255: {'contig': [2, 2, 2, 2], 'hapX_My_Sum': [12.0, 12.0, 11.0, 11.0]},
 726: {'contig': [2, 2, 2], 'hapX_My_Sum': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]},
 3353: {'contig': [2, 2, 2], 'hapX_My_Sum': [11.0, 11.0, 11.0]}}
```

Some explanation:

first we generate dictionaries for each group

```
In [87]: df[cols].groupby('PI_index') \
    ...:         .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('PI_index').to_dict('list'))
Out[87]:
PI_index
255     {'contig': [2, 2, 2, 2], 'hapX_My_Sum': [12.0,...
726     {'contig': [2, 2, 2], 'hapX_My_Sum': [0.0, 0.0...
3353    {'contig': [2, 2, 2], 'hapX_My_Sum': [11.0, 11...
dtype: object
```

now we can export rows as dictionary, setting corresponding index and using default `orient='dict'`

```
In [88]: df[cols].groupby('PI_index') \
    ...:         .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('PI_index').to_dict('list')) \
    ...:         .to_dict()
Out[88]:
{255: {'contig': [2, 2, 2, 2], 'hapX_My_Sum': [12.0, 12.0, 11.0, 11.0]},
 726: {'contig': [2, 2, 2], 'hapX_My_Sum': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]},
 3353: {'contig': [2, 2, 2], 'hapX_My_Sum': [11.0, 11.0, 11.0]}}
```

Comment: Yeah. I forgot to add but is there a way to **unselected** certain coulumns if undesired, but I don't want to drop them out from pandas data frame. Also, what if I only want one value in **contig** since they will be the same.

Comment: @everestial007, i've edited my answer for selecting only desired columns. I don't know yet how to reduce `contig`...

Comment: Thats ok. I should be able to take care of it by taking sometime. Thanks much

Comment: Thanks this answer worked. But, could you be kind to add the details to the process. Also, what is `to_dict('l')` doing? Is it `list`? And, why do we need `to_dict` twice. If you could explain the process it will help me and other learn and be independent. Thanks much !

Comment: @everestial007, sure, i've added some short explanation

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to think about it .
 1. Convert your record to array of dictionaries

```
df_arrDict = df.to_dict('record')
> [{'PI_index': 726.0,
    'contig': 2.0,
    'hapX_My_Sum': 0.0,
    'hapX_Sp_Sum': 3.5,
    'hapY_My_Sum': 12.0,
    'pos': 16229767.0},
    {....
    ]
```

2. Default dictionaries are good to group data

```
  from collections import  defaultdict
  by_PI = defaultdict(list)
  for df_dict in df_arrDict:
      feature = df_dict['PI_index']
      by_PI[feature].append(df_dict)
```

3. Finally convert back to Dictionary and you can use any methods or dict comprehensions as below

   ```
   by_PI_dict = { int(key):val for key,val in by_PI.items()}
   by_PI_dict[255]
   [{'PI_index': 255.0,
       'contig': 2.0,
       'hapX_My_Sum': 12.0,
       'hapX_Sp_Sum': 0.0,
       'hapY_My_Sum': 0.0,
       'pos': 16230491.0},
    {'PI_index': 255.0,
       'contig': 2.0,
       'hapX_My_Sum': 12.0,
       'hapX_Sp_Sum': 0.0,
       'hapY_My_Sum': 0.0,
       'pos': 16230503.0},
    {'PI_index': 255.0,
      'contig': 2.0,
      'hapX_My_Sum': 11.0,
      'hapX_Sp_Sum': 0.0,
      'hapY_My_Sum': 1.0,
      'pos': 16232072.0},
    {'PI_index': 255.0,
      'contig': 2.0,
      'hapX_My_Sum': 11.0,
      'hapX_Sp_Sum': 0.0,
      'hapY_My_Sum': 1.0,
      'pos': 16232072.0}]
   ```